# Proofs in the Appendix A of Sannikov (2007)

Tags: game-theory, continuous-time, repeated-games

I have a few questions about the proofs in Appendix A of Sannikov (2007), [Games with Imperfectly Observable Actions in Continuous Time](http://www.princeton.edu/~sannikov/gamesRRR.pdf).

1. In lemma 4, when he shows the Lipschitz continuity of $H_a(w,\theta)$ in $\theta$, he derives an auxiliary function $F(\theta^\prime)$, takes its derivative, and bounds that derivative (page 41). How does he get that bound? What is $|\mathcal{V}|$? How is he able to bound the factor involving $\beta^1$ and $\beta^2$?
2. In proposition 4, why does Lipschitz continuity of the objective guarantee continuity of the value function? Does this just follow from the [Maximum Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_theorem)? If so, why did we need Lipschitz continuity?
3. Also in proposition 4: why does the initial curvature being positive guarantee that it stays positive?
4. How does idempotency of $Q_i(a)$ guarantee that $\bar{Q} \geq 1$?